# Django Many To Many Insert Ordering

Tags: django, django-models

We have been struggling with this for a few days and have done lots of searches on the web.

We are trying to figure out how entries are saved in Django forms for many to many fields.

For example we have a news model that has a many to many relationship with images. When we add images to a news article e.g. images with id 10,2,14 we can see the post values are the following when saving a news article form:

- photos 10
- photos 2
- photos 14

When we look in the many to many intersection table the order has not been preserved. We can see no logic in the order the photos are inserted.

Hopefully that makes sense!

Many thanks for your answers in advance.

Arif

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Django doesn't guarantee to preserve the order of many-to-many relationships. If you need this, you should use a [`through`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) table with an explicit 'order' field.

Comment: Daniel,

That is a huge help, many thanks for your response.
Having looked at the docs you linked to that seems to solve the issue.

Thanks.

Arif

Comment: The order idea will help me too,thanks. But how would u define the query doing this? plz take a look at my model in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442797/how-to-model-a-reflexive-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: I used a created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) on my intermediary/through model to know the insertion order. Then I can use .order_by('created')

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is unfortunate because it seems like a very common requirement (or at least an important convenience) to maintain order for m2m data, and using a through model adds a fair bit of additional code and complexity. Looks like this may be a drop-in fix: https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-sortedm2m

Comment: Is sortedm2m still supported?   It shows as "build failing", and points to a defunct Travis service...

Answer (score 5):

Thankfully, order can now be preserved in a ManyToMany relationship **without** the extra complexity of using a *through* model using ***sortedm2m*** which is a drop-in replacement for django's own ManyToManyField.

https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-sortedm2m

Comment: BTW: If you check the code, *sortedm2m* uses internally also an intermediary `through`-table:
https://github.com/jazzband/django-sortedm2m/blob/master/sortedm2m/fields.py
But it encapsulates this complexity from your code.