# Order many-to-many field by the order values were inserted

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

```
# models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatar_photo_upload, blank=True)
    banner = models.ImageField(upload_to=banner_photo_upload, blank=True)

    bio = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=True)

    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_joined = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.user.username

class Friend(models.Model):
    # The friends, sender first, reciever second
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(Profile)

    # accepted or rejected
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rejected = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    time_added = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.accepted == False and self.rejected == False:
            return f'{" sent a request to ".join([i.user.username for i in self.friends.all()])}'
        else:
            if self.accepted == True and self.rejected == True:
                return f'{" was a friend of ".join([i.user.username for i in self.friends.all()])}'
            elif self.accepted == True and self.rejected == False:
                return f'{" is a friend of ".join([i.user.username for i in self.friends.all()])}'
            else:
                return f'{" was rejected as a friend by ".join([i.user.username for i in self.friends.all()])}'
```

The `friends` field is a `many-to-many field`,
Understanding my problem with an example:

for example -> Profile object `a` is created, and then Profile object `b`.
Now I add profile object `b` in the `friend` field and then object `a`, but the `friend` field orders them in `a` then `b`...

How do order them by time added.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Expected output: The same order in which the values were inserted.

Comment: Please share with us the `Profile` model as well.

Comment: I have edited and added the Profile model.

Comment: Nice, then the `order_by` is your friend. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by

You can use something like this `YOUR_MODEL_NAME.objects.filter(FILTER_FIELDS).order_by("-profile__date_joined")` for ordered by date_joined descending.

Comment: I could not make my question clear, what I want is order the field by the added time, meaning - ```b``` is added in and then ```a``` is added I expect the order to be ```b, a```, the order in which it was added the same order the output should be... So sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Django Many To Many Insert Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880530/django-many-to-many-insert-ordering)

Django doesn't guarantee to preserve the order of many-to-many relationships. If you need this, you should use a through table with an explicit 'order' field.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for ordering Django ManyToMany field by created id.

**Note: The relational database create a separate table.**

```
posts = user.posts.through.objects.all().order_by('-id') #In here user is a model. and posts is ManyToMany field. 
post_list = []
for post in posts:
    get_post = Post.objects.get(id=post.post_id) #Using through only return object id. So use for loop to get the object if required.
    post_list.append(get_post)
return post_list
```